# Android Firebase How to get the key of a pushed value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I get the push key (the one in the highlighted with blue pen)? 
I want to get that value in order to change the value of subjectName child.

[image: 1]

Comment: That would be called the *key*. All of the data in Firebase is stored as key:value pairs. Good info here [Getting Started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data) and [Snapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot)

Answer (score 7):

If you want to know what is the push key value before a write operation you have to do something like this:

```
//get the push key value
String key = mDatabase.child("posts").push().getKey();

//then you can write in that node in this way
mDatabase.child("posts").child(key).setValue(yourValue)
```

Comment: Worth noting that calling `push()` without parameters doesn't actually write anything to the database (you can't have a node with the value `null` after all)

Comment: Yes you don't have to write anything to the database, you have only to get the key reference (which is generated with the timestamp) and then push a value in that reference. It is shown also in the doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the .setValue() method to create/update the entity, you can add a CompletionListener to the second parameter and get the key from the fresh DatabaseReference exposed by the CompletionListener

Answer (score 0):

if you have unique subject code then you can use it and call updatechild method.it is in the firebase documentation.